# How to avoid battery spark when connecting it to a DC-DC-converter

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, capacitor-charging

I'm connecting a 40 V battery to a DC-DC converter that can step down a voltage from 40 V to 8 V. When I connect the terminals the battery gives off a spark. I've browsed some sites which say that this huge inrush current is due to the capacitors charging up, but I haven't found a practical solution to the problem. How can I suppress the spark?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507530/how-can-i-prevent-inrush-current-from-causing-sparks-when-i-connect-my-project-t

Answer (score 0):

Add a switch so that the spark is not on the battery terminal.

Even a fuse that is remote to the battery will make this safer.

I have seen batteries explode and cover the area in acid so it is not a situation to be taken lightly.

I had a similar issue when connecting my son's 1.5kW inverter to the 24V battery bank. I fitted one of those circuit breaker fuses and it now behaves well.